# How to make TD behaving like TR(row) with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a component that create dynamically html table. According to my need, I need to show td tags line by line as a block element not like column. How to do that by using CSS ?

Comment: Can you post the image? You should use padding margin etc to format your td look like a block

Comment: This sounds like a really horrible hack. I don't think you're going to find a solution that works in all browsers (old versions of IE are going to hate you!). If you explain a bit more clearly what you're actually trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest alternative solutions which may work better.

Comment: @Spudley  I decided to change my component that permits me to write my own html. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by applying `display: block` to the `td`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/wYA9K/

That works in all modern browsers except IE9..

Using `float: left; width: 100%` instead makes it also work in IE8/9:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvpzh/

Nothing will make it work in IE7.

Comment: What I understand is, all solutions have a cross browser problem. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/RBLDR/):

```
td{
    display: table-row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display: block` css property as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLFZq/)

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure this your expecting solution.

Please check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/mPdd7/2/

Answer (score -1):

you can use colspan attribute

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">some content</td>
</tr>
```

this will make a cell that spans two columns

Comment: This pushes the following cells to the right and does not make a table cell (td) to an table row.