# How to make each cell (<td>) behave like rows in css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-tables

I'm creating a mobile website for a pre-existing website (asp.net) and the layout was designed using tables. Is there any way to convert each cell in the table into a row in CSS so that I can fit it into the mobile screen or is there a better way (aside from changing the whole website which I'm not allowed to).
Basically, how do I turn a 2X4 table into a 1x8 table using CSS?

Comment: `"(aside from changing the whole website which I'm not allowed to)"` ? Why this is like people who won't upgrade from `IE6`

Comment: If that's the restriction you have I think it's best you make another set of tables for smaller screens.

Comment: @NickR - I would love to, but I'm not allowed to :(

Comment: I think I found the answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773862/how-to-make-td-behaving-like-trrow-with-css?rq=1 thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

add this to your mobile view css

```
td{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/knY3f/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `table-row` property:

```
tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
td{
    display:table-row;
    background:#efefef;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/395EC/).