# Chrome-specific CSS issue setting table cell to display:block

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773862/how-to-make-td-behaving-like-trrow-with-css) that seemingly had what I wanted. I am using chrome 32.0.1700.102 and even the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYA9K/) on the first answer amazingly works fine for me.

However, when I put the following html into a new file and open it up in chrome, the "computed styles" tab of the tds still show `display:table-cell;` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #block td {
                display: block;
                background: #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="block">
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this in firefox, I get the desired result:

[image: firefox vs chrome]

Here is a screenshot of chrome showing the display:block rule in the style tab but display:table-cell in the computed tab:

[image]

Comment: What happens with `#block td {display: block !important;}`

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic unfortunately that doesn't help

Comment: @AndyPerlitch same problem I was having today! Thanks for asking this question, it helped me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't see any `DOCTYPE` declared in the document, when you don't declare a doctype, Chrome overrides the `display: block;` with `display: table-cell;`

It works on JS Fiddle cuz they have doctype declared.

So use `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top of the document before `<html>` and it should fix the issue.

Comment: WOW. Mr. Alien not only are you the best kept government secret of the last century but you are also great at solving css issues. Well played, sir. Well played.

Comment: I have the same issue. My table is in an iframe whose doctype is not specified(cant specify too) and parent document has `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I thought iframe uses parent doc's doctype but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Mr. Alien THANKS!!! you saved me from big trouble!! Very good informatic well explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

I always define the doctype, but this issue started occuring after the last Chrome update 45.0.2454.85 in my responsive design. The stacked table cells would render as a hybrid of table-cell and table-row after resizing the browser at responsive breakpoints (media queries), or when switching from portrait to landscape and back (if landscape didn't stack the table cells and portrait did). This bug occurs only when there are more than two table cells.

The solution: In the containing table row `tr` set it to display:table-cell.

```
table.classname tr { display:table-cell !important; }
table.classname td { display:block; width:100% !important; }
```

Comment: This was the exact fix that helped me. It didn't make sense, I had the td set to "display: block" and yet it wasn't showing correctly, until I changed it to anything else in devtools and then back to "display: block" (as if Chrome was overriding it originally). Looks like Chrome doesn't like `display: table-row` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used `display: block;` in a galery situation, so no table, just an url with HP generated code.

`display: block;`,  nor display table-cell worked for me (I don´t have a table!)

For me `display: table;` worked like a charm.