# display block tables in chrome doesn't work

Tags: css

My problem is that i cannot manage to display block my tables .  I found that the problem exists on Chrome and for some just adding the `<!Doctype>` before the `<html>` tag works, but it is not my case.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: Provide an example and/or some code you've tried.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to change the display mode for the table.  Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want my td records from every tr to appear on separate lines. I have the same problem like this guy but the Doctype solution worked for him. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425138/chrome-specific-css-issue-setting-table-cell-to-displayblock

Answer (score 0):

In the containing `<tr>` set it to `display:table-cell`.

```
table.classname tr { display:table-cell !important; }
table.classname td { display:block; width:100% !important; }
```

EDIT: Here's a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/WebDevJoshB/pen/JYGBvB).

Answer (score 0):

In the containing `<tr>` set it to `display:flex` and allow wrap:

```css
table.classname tr { display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; }
```