# Media Query not kicking in for Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries

I have table showing on my [web page](http://homans.hitcalculate.com/calc) , the width of which exceeds that of the screen. So to make it presentable, I have used to the trick mentioned at [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) . The CSS is attached here for reference as well:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)  {
* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
}

td:before {

    float: left;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/*
Label the data
*/
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "A/C Model"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Coil Model"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Furnace/FanCoil"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "AHRI"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "SEER"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "EER"; }
td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "AFUE"; }
td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "HSPF"; }
td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Bryant Bonus"; }
td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Elec Rebate"; }
td:nth-of-type(11):before { content: "Furnace Rebate"; }
td:nth-of-type(12):before { content: "Federal Rebate"; }
td:nth-of-type(13):before { content: "Total Rebate"; }
}
```

The effect is perfectly visible on chrome as shown in this screenshot.[image]

However, on Safari (both desktop and iPhone) the table data is jumbled up.[image]

P.S: You can run the following sample query on the website to check:

```
 { outdoor: 'ac',
   indoor: 'Furnace coil',
   coolingtons: '2',
   furnace: 'New',
   fuel: 'Gas',
   venting: 'Condensing',
   state: 'Massachussetts',
   btuh: '60000',
   electricutility: 'National Grid',
   gasutility: 'Blackstone Gas' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your codes.Please try to change the `<!Doctype html5> to <!Doctype html>`

**Reference :** [Chrome-specific CSS issue setting table cell to display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425138/chrome-specific-css-issue-setting-table-cell-to-displayblock)

Even not coming the exact output in webkit browser.

**Refer this comments:**
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38527

After analyzing it --> The webkit browsers not over riding the display properties.whatever you change to table,come back to the same properties to **display:table-cell.**

Comment: Changing from `<!Doctype html5> to <!Doctype html>` fixed it. Thanks!